# Stop dropdown width from expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have two dynamic dropdown lists. The options displayed on the second dropdown depends on what was selected in the first dropdown. The first dropdown has 2 options. If the second option is selected, the values that appear on the second dropdown in response are very long strings (url to be exact). Is there any way that i can stop the width of the dropdown from expanding?

Here's the JSFiddle result:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgbw56vb/10/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/pgbw56vb/10/

```
<select id="kategorie_oder_seite"></select>

<select id="auswahl"></select>


var data = {
"Kategorie": ["Kraft", "Startseite", "Insurance", "Risk",],
"Seite": ["http://jsfiddle.net/tony089/pgbw56vb/2/", "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask"],
};


var $kategorien = $("#kategorie_oder_seite").on("change", function() {
var seiten = $.map(data[this.value], function(seite) {
    return $("<option />").text(seite);
});
$("#auswahl").empty().append(seiten);
});

for (var kategorie in data) {
$("<option />").text(kategorie).appendTo($kategorien);
}

$kategorien.change();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<select id="auswahl" style="width:150px;"></select>` - add fixed width to your select tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a certain width to the select with the `#auswahl` id as following :

CSS:

```
#auswahl {
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated several times here, you can limit the size of the second dropdown by adding a `width` or  `max-width` with CSS.

Or you can **limit the length of the strings** that you are showing as options inside the dropdown.

Something like

```
var seiten = $.map(data[this.value], function(seite) {
    return $("<option>" + seite.substring(0, 15) + "</option>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Use:

```
#auswahl{
    max-width:50px;
}
```

For example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#auswahl {
max-width:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

add this css class  to file

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS:

```
#auswahl{
    width:50%;
}
```